# Android jAudioTagger Problem - Reading mp3 file - VerifyError

Tags: android, tags, mp3, verifyerror

I have the following error but cannot workout the problem, i am READING MP3 files and the below error seems to come as it tries to WRITE MP4 files.

```
AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(m_file.get(x));
```

Error comes after calling the above and passing the first MP3 file

```
08-27 09:51:47.671: ERROR/dalvikvm(4485): Could not find class     'javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode', referenced from method     org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp4.Mp4TagWriter.write
08-27 09:51:47.671: WARN/dalvikvm(4485): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 303 (Ljavax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode;) in Lorg/jaudiotagger/audio/mp4/Mp4TagWriter;
08-27 09:51:47.671: WARN/dalvikvm(4485): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x1f at 0x00aa
08-27 09:51:47.671: WARN/dalvikvm(4485): VFY:  rejected Lorg/jaudiotagger/audio/mp4/Mp4TagWriter;.write (Lorg/jaudiotagger/tag/Tag;Ljava/io/RandomAccessFile;Ljava/io/RandomAccessFile;)V
08-27 09:51:47.671: WARN/dalvikvm(4485): Verifier rejected class Lorg/jaudiotagger/audio/mp4/Mp4TagWriter;
08-27 09:51:47.671: WARN/dalvikvm(4485): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001da28)
08-27 09:51:47.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485): Uncaught handler: thread MagentoBackground exiting due to uncaught exception
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485): java.lang.VerifyError: org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp4.Mp4TagWriter
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp4.Mp4FileWriter.<init>(Mp4FileWriter.java:36)
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO.prepareReadersAndWriters(AudioFileIO.java:244)
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO.<init>(AudioFileIO.java:182)
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO.getDefaultAudioFileIO(AudioFileIO.java:126)
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO.read(AudioFileIO.java:148)
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at it.cloudspace.rhythmrunner.main.getSongs(main.java:115)
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at it.cloudspace.rhythmrunner.main.access$3(main.java:103)
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at it.cloudspace.rhythmrunner.main$2.run(main.java:62)
08-27 09:51:47.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
08-27 09:51:47.871: INFO/Process(76): Sending signal. PID: 4485 SIG: 3
08-27 09:51:47.871: INFO/dalvikvm(4485): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-27 09:51:48.271: INFO/dalvikvm(4485): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-27 09:51:48.301: ERROR/vending(4501): com.android.vending.api.LocalAssetDatabase.buildPackageNameMap(): Multiple assets with package name com.google.android.apps.unveil
08-27 09:51:48.311: ERROR/vending(4501): com.android.vending.api.LocalAssetDatabase.buildPackageNameMap(): Multiple assets with package name com.amazon.kindle
08-27 09:51:54.061: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3189): GC freed 13924 objects / 712680 bytes in 590ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Android port is being put in place, the above error was due to some Swing libraries that aren't available in Android